# DJANGO FORMS.py 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django

Hi my problem is the next, I'm trying to do a Forms with filter raw sql but I can't solved this problem

```
'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Forms.py

```
class pruebaForm (forms.Form):
    userid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = users.objects.raw('SELECT userid FROM groupsmembers WHERE groupid=User.groupid'))
    softlimit = forms.IntegerField()
    hardlimit = forms.IntegerField()
    printerid = forms.ChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model = userpquota
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def asignarcuota_lista (request):
    f = userpquotaFilter(request.GET, queryset=userpquota.objects.all())
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = pruebaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            asignarcuota = form.save(commit=False)
            asignarcuota.save()
            messages.success(request,'Se ha asignadoº correctamente')
            return redirect('asignarcuota_lista',)
    else:
        form = pruebaForm()
    return render (request, 'pykota/asignarcuota_lista.html', {'filter': f, 'form': form})
```